# Specific Source Control Solution for VB6

Tags: version-control, versioning

My company has a specific requirement to be notified or warned when someone is about to make a change to a module in VB6 if someone else is also making changes to the same file.  I don't want to use locking if possible.

Also when the about to be modified, it should prompt the user to download the latest version from the server.

Thanks!

Comment: I would investigate `git` and it hooks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Basile Starynkevitch said, [git](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) is the right thing to look at. 
It has a mechanism to prevent you to make a change to a repository if someone else made a change to it. git prompts you to download (fetch) the last version from the server and merge it with your version before submitting it again.

See [this git documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) for more understanding.

Comment: I should gave mentioned that we need to host the server internally. Does git allow to be hosted on a private network?

Comment: Also is there plugins for vb6?

Comment: Go on and [read the doc](http://git-scm.com/). Git is a distributed source control software : it does not need a server. And you can use it via the command line, which is the recommended way.

Comment: I understand.  However we are looking for a more out of the box solution with plugins for the IDE